# # include <GL/glut.h> File Not Found in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

I am trying to run an openGL program in Xcode, but I am getting an error in one line of the following code:

```
#ifdef __MAC__
# include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
# include <GL/glut.h>   // in this line, I am getting the error that the file is not found
#endif
```

I have added the GLUT framework and openGL framework - not sure if this is related).

Comment: The proper thing to test for would be `__APPLE__`, not `__MAC__`

Answer (score 4):

If I get that error.I will write the bellow.
This way is only works OSX.

```
#ifndef __MAC__
#define __MAC__ 1
#endif

#ifdef __MAC__
# include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
# include <GL/glut.h>   // in this line, I am getting the error that the file is not found
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<GLUT/glut.h>` instead of `<GL/glut.h>` on all platforms.

The former has been deprecated in the latest updates and you might receive warnings.